# Magento - How to update shipping address using customer_save_after event?

Tags: php, magento

I am trying to create or update default shipping address for a customer using `customer_save_after` event (based on some custom registration fields) when customer tries to create new account or edit his account.

Here goes the portion of the Observer model code:

```
...
$customer   = $observer->getEvent()->getCustomer();
if ($customer->getId() && $otherConditionIsValid){
    $dataShipping = array(
        'firstname' => $someFixedFirstName,
        'lastname'  => $someFixedLastName,
        'street'    => array($someFixedStreetLine),
        'city'      => $someFixedCity,
        'region'    => $someFixedState,
        'region_id' => '',
        'postcode'  => $someFixedZipcode,
        'country_id' => $someFixedCountry,
        'telephone' => $someFixedTelephone,
    );
    $customerAddress = Mage::getModel('customer/address');
    if($defaultShippingId = $customer->getDefaultShipping()){ //if customer already has default shipping address
        $customerAddress->load($defaultShippingId);
    }
    $customerAddress->setData($dataShipping)
                    ->setCustomerId($customer->getId())
                    ->setIsDefaultShipping('1')
                    ->setSaveInAddressBook('1');
    $customer->addAddress($customerAddress); #setting Shipping Address to be added/updated
    //When i try to use below commented code, script gets called for infinite times, finally running out of memory
    /*try{
        $customerAddress->save();
    }catch(Exception $e){
        Mage::log('Address Save Error::' . $e->getMessage());
    }*/
}
...
```

Above code works fine when customer creates a new account. However default shipping address don't get updated when customer tries to edit the custom registration field from `My Account > Account Information`

So my main concern is how to update the shipping address using `$customer` object or any other code using `customer_save_after` event.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you would like to do the following when the `customer_save_after` event gets fired:

1. If the customer does not have a default shipping address, then create one with the values in the $dataShipping array.
2. If the customer does have a default shipping address, then update it's values with those in the $dataShipping array.

If this is indeed what you are looking for then please try the code below (obviously you need to take care of where the values for the $otherConditionIsValid and $dataShipping variables):

```
$customer = $observer->getEvent()->getCustomer();
if (! $customer->getId() || ! $otherConditionIsValid){
    return $this;                
}

$dataShipping = array(
    'firstname'  => $someFixedFirstName,
    'lastname'   => $someFixedLastName,
    'street'     => array($someFixedStreetLine),
    'city'       => $someFixedCity,
    'region'     => $someFixedState,
    'region_id'  => '',
    'postcode'   => $someFixedZipcode,
    'country_id' => $someFixedCountry,
    'telephone'  => $someFixedTelephone,
);

$customerAddress = Mage::getModel('customer/address');

if ($defaultShippingId = $customer->getDefaultShipping()){
     $customerAddress->load($defaultShippingId); 
} else {   
     $customerAddress
        ->setCustomerId($customer->getId())
        ->setIsDefaultShipping('1')
        ->setSaveInAddressBook('1')
     ;   

     $customer->addAddress($customerAddress);
}            

try {
    $customerAddress
        ->addData($dataShipping)
        ->save()
    ;           
} catch(Exception $e){
    Mage::log('Address Save Error::' . $e->getMessage());
}

return $this;
```

Comment: Thanks a ton Drew! That worked like a charm. I think conditional setting of shipping address did the trick. Cheers!

Comment: doesn't work for me - I get `Call to a member function getDefaultShipping() on a non-object`, because it appears that `$customer = $observer->getEvent()->getCustomer()` returns customer's id instead of customer object

Answer (score 0):

```
$address = Mage::getModel("customer/address");              
   $address->setCustomerId($this->customerID());
   $address->setFirstname(Mage::app()->getRequest()->getPost("event_firstname"));
   $address->setLastname(Mage::app()->getRequest()->getPost("event_lastname"));
   $address->setCountryId('AE');
   $address->setCity(Mage::app()->getRequest()->getPost("event_city"));
   $address->setStreet(Mage::app()->getRequest()->getPost("event_address"));
   $address->setTelephone(Mage::app()->getRequest()->getPost("event_mobile"));
   $address->save();
```